# node async foreachof delay between loops

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, foreach

I have an object over which I am iterating. Now for each of key, value pair in this object, I need to call a function which makes a i/o request but I need to wait between these iterations. That is the function would iterate, read the first object, pass it to function and wait for n milliseconds, after n milliseconds it will read second pair, pass it to function and wait again till the objects in the list get over. How do I do this?

Currently this is outline of my code

```
async.forEachOfSeries(object1, 
    function(value, key, callback) {    
        //send switch status
        if(object1.key1 == some condition){
            sql.query1
        }
        some io request based on query result
        callback();
        want some delay here
    }, 
    function(err) {
        if( err ) {
            handle error
        } 
        else {
            report success
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Try this - 

async.forEachOfSeries(object1, 
    function(value, key, callback) {    
        //send switch status
        if(object1.key1 == some condition){
            sql.query1
        }
        some io request based on query result
        setTimeout(function () {
              callback();
            }, 10000)
    }, 
    function(err) {
        if( err ) {
            handle error
        } 
        else {
            report success
        }
    }
)

Set the timer delay to whatever time you want. Hope this helps.
```

Comment: Doesn't help. The io requests still fireup without delays.

Comment: @RishabhKaushik it is working for me, what kind of io you are firing ? Callback() here is iterator, there will be delay in next iteration and not in firing io

Comment: The io is mqtt publish. Each iteration consist of one such request, I tried this bit but all the mqtt requests are happening simultaneously though I put a 10000 ms delay there.

Comment: can i see that piece of code, you can remove any sensitive info there.

Comment: It worked for me. Sorry. Actually I was using this method in similar but different function and was viewing result of another function. Thanks for help.